# module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'import_event'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I'm playing around a code from a book, however, there is an error that I can't manage to solve. This is my code:

```
from tensorboard.plugins.hparams import api_pb2
from tensorboard.plugins.hparams import summary as hparams_summary

def run_experiment(run_dir, hparams):
  writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir)
  summary_start = hparams_summary.session_start_pb(hparams=hparams)
  with writer.as_default():
    accuracy = train_test_hp(hparams)
    summary_end = hparams_summary.session_end_pb(api_pb2.STATUS_SUCCESS)
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',accuracy,step=1,description="The accuracy")
    tf.summary.import_event(tf.compat.v1.Event(summary=summary_start).SerializeToString())
    tf.summary.import_event(tf.compat.v1.Event(summary=summary_end).SerializeToString())
  return accuracy
```

This is the error I got:

> module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute
> 'import_event'

I'm using colab. Please give me ideas about resolving the error. Your help means a lot to me!

Comment: I could solve my problem. Because I thought that this might be helpful, I'll post it as answer in the hope to be profiting the other people.

Answer (score 1):

Changing lines:

```
tf.summary.import_event(tf.compat.v1.Event(summary=summary_start).SerializeToString())
tf.summary.import_event(tf.compat.v1.Event(summary=summary_end).SerializeToString())
```

to:

```
tf.compat.v1.summary.Event(summary=summary_start).SerializeToString()
tf.compat.v1.summary.Event(summary=summary_end).SerializeToString()
```

solves the problem.